Excel sumup all volume in one hour
I would like to sum up all the values for the inspection line from 21:00 hours to 21:59 in cell C78 on sheet 1.  In this example C78 would equal 416.
I have tried sumifs but I dont think this is the solution.  Maybe a sumproduct? but just can't get it to work.  Any support welcome.
Sheet 1:

Sheet 2:


Sheet 1



Resource Group
Resource
12/06/2024 21 00
12/06/2024 22 00




Prep Lines
INSPECTION LINE - N1 NIGHTS






Sheet 2



Resource
12/06/2024 21 00
12/06/2024 21 01
12/06/2024 21 02
12/06/2024 21 03
12/06/2024 21 04
12/06/2024 21 05
12/06/2024 21 06
12/06/2024 21 07
12/06/2024 21 08
12/06/2024 21 09
12/06/2024 21 10
12/06/2024 21 11
12/06/2024 21 12
12/06/2024 21 13
12/06/2024 21 14
12/06/2024 21 15
12/06/2024 21 16
12/06/2024 21 17
12/06/2024 21 18
12/06/2024 21 19
12/06/2024 21 20
12/06/2024 21 21
12/06/2024 21 22
12/06/2024 21 23
12/06/2024 21 24
12/06/2024 21 25
12/06/2024 21 26
12/06/2024 21 27
12/06/2024 21 28
12/06/2024 21 29
12/06/2024 21 30
12/06/2024 21 31
12/06/2024 21 32
12/06/2024 21 33
12/06/2024 21 34
12/06/2024 21 35
12/06/2024 21 36
12/06/2024 21 37
12/06/2024 21 38
12/06/2024 21 39
12/06/2024 21 40
12/06/2024 21 41
12/06/2024 21 42
12/06/2024 21 43
12/06/2024 21 44
12/06/2024 21 45
12/06/2024 21 46
12/06/2024 21 47
12/06/2024 21 48
12/06/2024 21 49
12/06/2024 21 50
12/06/2024 21 51
12/06/2024 21 52
12/06/2024 21 53
12/06/2024 21 54
12/06/2024 21 55
12/06/2024 21 56
12/06/2024 21 57
12/06/2024 21 58
12/06/2024 21 59
12/06/2024 22 00
12/06/2024 22 01
12/06/2024 22 02
12/06/2024 22 03
12/06/2024 22 04
12/06/2024 22 05
12/06/2024 22 06
12/06/2024 22 07
12/06/2024 22 08
12/06/2024 22 09
12/06/2024 22 10
12/06/2024 22 11
12/06/2024 22 12
12/06/2024 22 13
12/06/2024 22 14
12/06/2024 22 15
12/06/2024 22 16
12/06/2024 22 17
12/06/2024 22 18
12/06/2024 22 19
12/06/2024 22 20
12/06/2024 22 21
12/06/2024 22 22
12/06/2024 22 23
12/06/2024 22 24
12/06/2024 22 25
12/06/2024 22 26
12/06/2024 22 27
12/06/2024 22 28
12/06/2024 22 29
12/06/2024 22 30
12/06/2024 22 31
12/06/2024 22 32
12/06/2024 22 33
12/06/2024 22 34
12/06/2024 22 35
12/06/2024 22 36
12/06/2024 22 37
12/06/2024 22 38
12/06/2024 22 39
12/06/2024 22 40
12/06/2024 22 41
12/06/2024 22 42
12/06/2024 22 43
12/06/2024 22 44
12/06/2024 22 45
12/06/2024 22 46
12/06/2024 22 47
12/06/2024 22 48




INSPECTION LINE - N1 NIGHTS
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13

















































































You may want to only share some data to reproduce your problem, no more. Postaling as markdown table helps us help you: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Great tip, much appreciated.  Will look to amend first thing in the morning.  Thank you.

Hi, Alan as per your given screenshot the output will be 416 and shouldn't be 377 is that a typo on your end, could you clarify please? This is because if past 21:31 there are no values as well as all values from 21:00 till that time is same as 13

Here is one way of accomplishing the desired output, also it shouldn't 377 as per the given example instead it would be 416 as per the screenshot posted.


• Formula used in cell C78
=SUM(FILTER(CHOOSEROWS(Sheet2!$Q:$DU,XMATCH($B78,Sheet2!$H:$H)),
  (Sheet2!$Q$2:$DU$2>=C$1)*(Sheet2!$Q$2:$DU$2<=C$1+TIME(,59,59))))


Another alternative way using FILTER() + SUM() function:
=SUM(FILTER(Sheet2!$Q$3:$DU$150,
    (Sheet2!$Q$2:$DU$2>=C$1)*
    (Sheet2!$Q$2:$DU$2<=C$1+TIME(,60,-1)))*
    ($B78=Sheet2!$H$3:$H$150))


One can replace this <=C$1+TIME(,59,59) or <=C$1+TIME(,60,-1) with this as well <(C$1+1/24)


Thanks for the options, will dive on this first thing tomorrow morning (England).  Have also "brought you a coffee".  Thanks for all your support.

No rush at all, please take your time. I have used this Markdown Table Generator Credit to the creator JohnFraney.ca it is relatively easy to use. You just need to copy the data from your excel and paste in the given website. generate and copy paste it here. Thank you very much !!
